# How to user previous resultset into next query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to generate access token if username and password will match in users table. But how can I use previous returned value to next insert query? I have marked missing value with ###I don't know###.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAccessToken]
    @userId varchar(50),
    @password varchar(50)
AS
   SELECT Id 
   FROM Users 
   WHERE UserId = @userId AND Password = @password 

   IF @@ROWCOUNT != 0 
   BEGIN
       SET @token = NEWID();

       INSERT INTO AccessTokens (Token, UserId) 
       VALUES(CONVERT(varchar(255), @token), ###I Don't Know###)
        END
       RETURN 0
   END
```

Please help me. Thanks, in advance.

Comment: `INSERT INTO AccessTokens(Token, UserID) VALUES(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),@token), @userID)`  You pass @userID into the stored procedure, so you simply need to ad it as the second value to insert into the table `AccessTokens`.

Comment: Presumably, you will never have more than one user with the same `UserId` and `Password`?

Answer (score 2):

Simply pass the `@userId` as your second parameter for `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO AccessTokens (Token, UserId) 
VALUES(CONVERT(varchar(255), @token), @userId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAccessToken]
    @userId varchar(50),
    @password varchar(50)
AS
   DECLARE @ID INT
   SELECT @ID = Id 
   FROM Users 
   WHERE UserId = @userId AND Password = @password 

   IF (@ID IS NOT NULL )
   BEGIN
       SET @token = NEWID();

       INSERT INTO AccessTokens (Token, UserId) 
       VALUES(CONVERT(varchar(255), @token), @ID)

       RETURN 0
   END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use option with INSERT .. SELECT .. pattern

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAccessToken]
@userId varchar(50),
@password varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO AccessTokens (Token, UserId)
  SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), Id
  FROM Users 
  WHERE UserId = @userId AND Password = @password
END
```

Comment: What happens if there is no match with username and password ?

Comment: The SELECT statement will returne by 0 rows and therefore the INSERT statement will insert 0 rows. Result of execution of procedure will be 0